# Pandas - Aggregating grouped data provided certain criteria is met

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a time series of the valuation of a stock portfolio, by aggregating time series valuation data on the individual stock holdings of that portfolio. The problem I have is that on certain dates there may not be a valuation for a given stock holding and thus aggregating on that date would produce erroneous results.

The solution I have come up with is to exclude dates for which valuation (actually price) data doesn't exist for a given holding and then aggregate on these dates where I have complete data. The procedure I use is as follows:

```
# Get the individual holding valuation data
valuation = get_valuation(portfolio = portfolio, df = True)

# Then next few lines retrieve the dates for which I have complete price data for the
# assets that comprise this portflio
# First get a list of the assets that this portfolio contains (or has contained).
unique_assets = valuation['asset'].unique().tolist()

# Then I get the price data for these assets
ats = get_ats(assets = unique_assets, df = True )[['data_date','close_price']]

# I mark those dates for which I have a 'close_price' for each asset:
ats = ats.groupby('data_date')['close_price'].agg({'data_complete':lambda x: len(x) == len(unique_assets)} ).reset_index()

# And extract the corresponding valid dates.
valid_dates = ats['data_date'][ats['data_complete']]

# Filter the valuation data for those dates for which I have complete data:
valuation = valuation[valuation['data_date'].apply(lambda x: x in valid_dates.values)]

# Group by date, and sum the individual hodling valuations by date, to get the Portfolio valuation
portfolio_valuation = valuation[['data_date','valuation']].groupby('data_date').agg(lambda df: sum(df['valuation'])).reset_index()
```

My question is two fold:

1) The above approach feels quite convoluted, and I am confident that Pandas has a better way of implementing my solution. Any suggestions?

2) The approach I have used isn't ideal. The best method is that for those dates for which we have no valuation data (for a given holding) we should use the most recent valuation for that holding. So let's say I am calculating the valuation of the portfolio on the 21 June 2012 and have valuation data for GOOG on that date but for APPL only on the 20 June 2012. Then the valuation for the portfolio on 21 June 2012 should still be the sum of these two valuations. Is there a efficient way to do this in Pandas? I want to avoid having to iterate through the data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some combination of resample and/or fillna is going to get you what you're looking for (realize this is coming a little late!).

Go grab your data just like you're doing. You get back this things with a few gaps. Check out this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2012-01-01', periods=10, freq='2D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20).reshape(10,2),index=dates)
```

So now you have this data that has lots of gaps in it -- but you want to have this daily resolution data.

Just do:

```
df.resample('1D')
```

This will fill in your dataframe with a bunch of NaNs where you have missing data. And then when you do aggregations on them, just use functions (e.g., np.nansum, np.mean) that ignore NaNs!

Still a little unclear on the exact format of the data you've got. Hope it helps.